# smtp.sendgrid.net connection refused to connect on web server.... correctly working in localhost

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, sendgrid

I am using sendgrid to send mail in my laravel application . I successfully tested application on localhost its working fine with mail facility also. but as i deployed to web server its started showing error " Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host smtp.sendgrid.net [Connection refused #111] ".
Thanks in advance.
[Image Showing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUh8L.jpg)
php artisan config:clear ,cache:clear and config:cache i tried all .... but nothing works.

.env file

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=USERNAME
MAIL_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

config/mail.php

```
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.sendgrid.net'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'email@email.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'From Name'),
    ],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

        'stream' => [
       'ssl' => [
          'allow_self_signed' => true,
          'verify_peer' => false,
          'verify_peer_name' => false,
       ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver for sending mails using sendgrid and its working fine for me. get it on [GITHUB](https://github.com/s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked for any restrictions at your hosting provider regarding outgoing SMTP port or `SMTP server` ?
Try the different ports as advised by [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/integrating-with-the-smtp-api/#smtp-ports) :

Comment: So i would check for any restriction imposed by your webhost to connect to external SMTP servers. Who is your hosting provider ?

Answer (score 0):

I Experienced this while using a Linode server. Apparently, Some service provide like Linode blocks an SMTP port until you reach out to them via support and ask them for unblock before you can use that PORT